# Only update values that need updating

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written the following script;

```
----------------
-- GLOBAL FAMILY DEDUPLICATION
----------------
--Global Family Deduplication of parents
update mstr
    SET 
        IsGlobalFamilyUnique = case 
            when (rn > 1 and IsGlobalFamilyUnique is null) then 0 
            when (rn = 1 and IsGlobalFamilyUnique is null) then 1
            else IsGlobalFamilyUnique end,
        GlobalFamilyDupID = [NewGlobalFamilyDupID],
        GroupIdentifier = ControlNumber
    from(
    select
        ControlNumber,
        MD5hash,
        IsglobalFamilyUnique,
        GlobalFamilyDupID,
        TopLvlGuid,
        GroupIdentifier,
        first_value(ControlNumber) over (partition by [MD5Hash] order by ID) [NewGlobalFamilyDupID],
        row_number() over (partition by [MD5Hash] order by ID asc) [RN]
    from ( --we only need non duplicated parents, and the unique set for deduplication
        select * from dbo.tblMaster where ischild = 0 and (IsGlobalFamilyUnique = 1 or IsGlobalFamilyUnique is null)
    )toDedupe
)mstr
```

Test data:

```
 declare @testdata as table (
    controlnumber nvarchar(100),
    MD5Hash nvarchar(100),
    IsGlobalFamilyUnique bit,
    GlobalFamilyDupId nvarchar(50),
    TopLvlGuid nvarchar(50),
    IsChild bit
)

insert into @testdata values
('BUL00000001','a0e0e90fe689ad07b65c461097558837',NULL,NULL,'000049d2-4edd-4ac9-8a14-ceb08e7b9883',0),
('BUL00000002','7072a5bcb002868823b8637b7f6b70fb',NULL,NULL,'000049d2-4edd-4ac9-8a14-ceb08e7b9883',1),
('BUL00000003','3895486d531c251126244cd63861fa3a',NULL,NULL,'000049d2-4edd-4ac9-8a14-ceb08e7b9883',1),
('BUL00000004','46a6eb25985931c9f15dafe3c4fe88ce',NULL,NULL,'00005819-661b-47ed-8044-77872b39487e',0),
('BUL00000005','5cd287d2ed56b868c11e1a0ea37e36bb',NULL,NULL,'000302ec-6bf7-433c-bdf3-be3aa0420468',0),
('BUL00000006','4a1335a5e09a1e6ba73b6004b70742b0',NULL,NULL,'0003df89-d7f2-4824-9364-a40d4ca6dcae',0),
('BUL00000007','feeb4fd491b8c6584f740154278b8494',NULL,NULL,'0005cd66-db18-4f63-a61d-c901033a69da',0),
('BUL00000008','689ab2a7527b0db4c3717939da2db52f',NULL,NULL,'0005cd66-db18-4f63-a61d-c901033a69da',1),
('BUL00000009','9cc73a89f66df1140622af27aa4c03fd',NULL,NULL,'0005cd66-db18-4f63-a61d-c901033a69da',1),
('BUL00000010','36ebcbd2fe90b724c0cd71012722266d',NULL,NULL,'0005cd66-db18-4f63-a61d-c901033a69da',1)
```

However I don't like that every time the script is run, it will be setting the `IsGlobalFamilyUnique` column, even if it has been previously set. It seems like a waste of resources and potentially dangerous thing to do.

I want the script to only set the `IsGlobalFamilyUnqiue` field for data that has not yet been deduplicated, i.e. has a `IsGlobalFamilyUnique` column is set to `NULL`. It should only de-duplicate where `IsChild` is `0` and against data that is unique, i.e. `IsGlobalFamilyUnique` is `1`.

How can I re-write this code to make it more efficient and remove the risk to potentially overwrite already set data?

Comment: It's not really a big waste of resources no. If you don't want to effect the column however, then you'll have to do away with a "one size fits all" solution and complete the updates on rows that don't have a value for `GlobalFamilyDupId` separately to those that do. You can't supply a column name in the `SET` clause, and expect SQL Server to "only sometime" complete that operation; much like you can't supply a column in a `SELECT` clause, but because `x = y` don't return it. You'd need either 2 queries, or dynamic SQL (which seems more overkill).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the other values are being set, there is essentially no overhead at all.  The overhead for an update tends to be:

- Locking resources
- Logging the action
- Dealing with dirty writes

The rest all occurs in memory.  In fact, SQL Server probably constructs the *entire* record in memory, copies it to a page in memory and then writes out the entire page (actually, I think it is a group of four pages).  Whether one column or three columns change, there is almost no difference.

Now, if all three columns might remain the same, then there is an optimization.  Just use a `where` clause to limit the updates to records that have changed.

Comment: Will it not make a difference say if, for example, there were 5 million entries in the table, and I then run the code to de-duplicate a further 1 million records. The script will be updating the `IsGlobalFamilyUnique` column 6 million times instead of 1 million?

Comment: @Sam . . . The database doesn't really update columns; the database updates *pages*.  If you are already updating a column in the record, you will have a dirty page.  The test for the additional column really is negligible compared to all the other work in an update.